# Is a full specification of a family of subsets also a full specification of the sigma-algebra it generates?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $C$ be a family of subsets of $\Omega$, and $G(C)$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $C$.

Assume that $f \in C$ is a "full specification" for $C$, meaning that for all $s \in C$ either $f \subseteq s$ or $f \subseteq \Omega \backslash s$. Can we prove that is also a full specification for $G(C)$ (meaning that for all $s \in G(C)$ either $f \subseteq s$ or $f \subseteq \Omega \backslash s$)? If so, how?

Some extra background: it seems intuitively clear to me that this should be true. But I'm struggling to prove it rigorously. My issue is that I don't really understand what explicit recipe we use to calculate $G(C)$. I know that it's something like $C$ together with everything obtained from $C$ via complements and countable unions". But this definition still seems a bit vague. For example, is it enough to first take the closure of $C$ under countable unions, and then the closure of that larger family under complements? Or do I have to keep on going iteratively, taking unions, then complements, then unions, then complements? And then if so, is it enough to iterate a finite number of times, or a countable number of times, or might I need an uncountable number of these steps?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicitly formulate $G(C)$.  Instead, define the condition

$$f\subseteq s \text{ or } f\subseteq \Omega\backslash s\text{,} \tag{*}$$

and then argue that the set of $s\in G(C)$ satisfying (*) forms a $\sigma$-algebra itself, and is therefore all of $G(C)$ by the definition of $G(C)$ as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $C$.

Indeed, the only nontrvial thing to show is that you are closed under countable unions, but this is pretty straightforward, since if $s_i$ is a sequence satisfying (*) then either $f\subseteq s_i$ for some $i$, whereby $f\subseteq \bigcup_i s_i$, or $f\cap s_i=\emptyset$ for all $s_i$, whereby $f\cap \bigcup_i s_i=\emptyset$.

Comment: Amazing, thank you!

Comment: @nick89  No problem, glad I can help! By the way, the technique used here is very common for proving that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a set has a given property, it's quite convenient.